# how to implement Google MAP in objectify with nearest location

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

we have been developing a application(find nearest hotel) with objectify in Google app engine.
 need help how to find the nearest location (around 5km) in objectify datastore from current location
would be great if find the sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Efficient way for geospatial query on AppEngine is to use Search API 
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/search/

Other ways would be GeoHash in datastore or MongoDB